# Can't iterate through a list in python

Tags: python, mysql-connector

After recieving data from mysql connector, when I try to iterate over the list, python keeps telling me the data is of type int:

The execute() and fetchall() statements:

```
def top_sellers(self):
        q = '''select Item, sum(Quantity) from purchases group by Item;'''
        self.cursor.execute(q)
        s = self.cursor.fetchall()
        print(s)
        print(type(s))
        for i in len(s):
            print(i)
```

The above code exits with:

```
[('beep', Decimal('3')), ('item1', Decimal('39')), ('Mask', Decimal('53')), ('Mask1', Decimal('2'))]
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projekt-red/index.py", line 326, in <module>
    main(id, password)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projekt-red/index.py", line 324, in main
    x.load_prompt(acc_type)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projekt-red/index.py", line 301, in load_prompt
    self.stats()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projekt-red/index.py", line 243, in stats
    self.top_sellers()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projekt-red/index.py", line 265, in top_sellers
    for i in len(list(s)):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `len(s)` returns an `int`. You probably want `for i in s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len(s)` is an integer, which is not iterable.
If you want to iterate `n` times, with `n = len(s)`, you need to replace `len(s)` by `range(len(s))` like so:

```py
def top_sellers(self):
        q = '''select Item, sum(Quantity) from purchases group by Item;'''
        self.cursor.execute(q)
        s = self.cursor.fetchall()
        print(s)
        print(type(s))
        for i in range(len(s)):
            print(i)
```

Edit:
This will print all the indices. If you want to print the results stored in `s`, then simply remove the `len()` and `range()`, just keeping `for i in s`. Or alternatively, keep it as above and replace the print statement by `print(s[i])`.

Comment: s is most likely not an integer, `range(s)` will not work. Did you mean `range(len(s))`?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, i'll edit thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through the array by using the len() function, you can iterate using blank variables. Len() is for integers, and there are strings in your list. If I were you I would do...

```
def top_sellers(self):
        q = '''select Item, sum(Quantity) from purchases group by Item;'''
        self.cursor.execute(q)
        s = self.cursor.fetchall()
        print(s)
        print(type(s))
        for row in self:
            for elem in row:
                print(elem)
```

And will return...

```
beep
3
item1
39
Mask
53
Mask1
2
```

If you wanted to print "('beep', '3')", just get rid of "for elem in row" and move the print statement into the other for statement.